# Make a GET with Guzzle in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, guzzle

I have an API, and make GET to it via Postman:

```
Ex.http://site/api/users.count
```

I got

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": {
        "count": 8
    }
}
```

I've tried to use Guzzle:

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle

Using version ^6.3 for guzzlehttp/guzzle                                                                                          
./composer.json has been updated                                                                                                  
Loading composer repositories with package information                                                                            
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                                                                                     
  - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (v1.3.1)                                                                                       
    Downloading: 100%                                                                                                             

  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1)                                                                                           
    Loading from cache                                                                                                            

  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.4.2)                                                                                            
    Loading from cache                                                                                                            

  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.3.0)                                                                                          
    Downloading: 100%                                                                                                             

Writing lock file                                                                                                                 
Generating autoload files                                                                                                         
> php artisan clear-compiled                                                                                                      

> php artisan optimize                                                                                                            

Generating optimized class loader
```

---

## include it

I add these 2 lines on top of my class

```
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

---

## use it

```
$client = new Client();
$res = $client->request('GET','http://site/api/users.count');
```

---

## result

**dd($res->getStatusCode());**

I got `200`

**dd($res->getBody());**

```
Stream {#662 ▼
  -stream: stream resource @272 ▼
    wrapper_type: "PHP"
    stream_type: "TEMP"
    mode: "w+b"
    unread_bytes: 0
    seekable: true
    uri: "php://temp"
    options: []
  }
  -size: null
  -seekable: true
  -readable: true
  -writable: true
  -uri: "php://temp"
  -customMetadata: []
}
```

**dd($res);**

I got

```
Response {#664 ▼
  -reasonPhrase: "OK"
  -statusCode: 200
  -headers: array:4 [▼
    "Connection" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "Keep-Alive"
    ]
    "Content-Length" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "61"
    ]
    "Content-Type" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    ]
    "Date" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "Wed, 18 Oct 2017 18:01:50 GMT"
    ]
  ]
  -headerNames: array:4 [▼
    "connection" => "Connection"
    "content-length" => "Content-Length"
    "content-type" => "Content-Type"
    "date" => "Date"
  ]
  -protocol: "1.1"
  -stream: Stream {#662 ▼
    -stream: stream resource @272 ▼
      wrapper_type: "PHP"
      stream_type: "TEMP"
      mode: "w+b"
      unread_bytes: 0
      seekable: true
      uri: "php://temp"
      options: []
    }
    -size: null
    -seekable: true
    -readable: true
    -writable: true
    -uri: "php://temp"
    -customMetadata: []
  }
}
```

---

## expected result

I am hoping to get a similar result like this :

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": {
        "count": 8
    }
}
```

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see by the response headers that everything went OK. Status code is 200, `Content-Length` is not 0, etc.

The body of the response is in the `body` property of `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response` and it's a [`GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream`](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/psr7.html#body). You can access it with the `getBody()` method.

You can use `read($n)` to read `n` bytes from the response, or get the whole response by casting the `Stream` to a string, either implicitly (via `echo`) or explicitly (with a cast operator):

```
var_dump((string) $res->getBody()); // explicitly
echo $res->getBody(); // implicitly
```

For future reference, you can use the [debug mode](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#debug) to see more information about the whole request:

```
$res = $client->request('GET','http://site/api/users.count', ["debug" => true]);
```

Comment: Do I need to add `use GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream;` on top of my file ?

Comment: No, you get a `Stream` instance so you don't need to `use` it.

Comment: What do you mean when you said this ? `The body of the response is in the body property of GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response and it's a GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream. You can access it with the getBody() method.`

Comment: @ihue `dd()` is doing a `var_dump()` behind the scenes so you'll get the Stream instance. Cast it to string to get the body in a string: `dd((string) $res->getBody());`

Comment: How can prevent my page not to crash the data is not there ?

Comment: That's great! I don't understand what you mean. What do you mean "the data is not there"? API endpoint is not found? Maybe this is better as another question :)

Comment: Ok. I will ask another question, please look into it ok seem like you know a lot about guzzle and php. if u don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$response->getBody();` you can also do things like 
`->getStatusCode();` Try and see their docs, there are a lot of options but to get the content use the getBody function

In your exact case `dd($res->getBody());`